# Input field not updated upon ngModel change

Tags: angularjs

So I created an Angular directive that can bind input to an array of strings. But whenever I try to remove an item from the array programmatically, the model does not get reflected on the input field. It seems like $modelValue is not updated either. Can someone explain why angular is behaving this way?

```
  <input array-model ng-model="inputList">
  <button type="button" ng-click="removeLastItem()">
    Remove last element from the list
  </button>


$scope.removeLastItem = function() {
  $scope.inputList.pop();
};
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r19mbv1r/

Comment: check this updaed fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/r19mbv1r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the function of a `pop` does not trigger an array of changed event.

Apparently, $formatters works on the principle `$watch` not `$WatchCollection`.

We can fix this. Each time you delete an array element to produce its initializing.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/d2fhrrch/).

```js
angular.module('SomeApp', [])
  .controller('SomeAppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputList = [];
    $scope.removeLastItem = function() {
      $scope.inputList = $scope.inputList.slice(0,$scope.inputList.length-1);
    };
  })
  .directive('arrayModel', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
          console.log("Inside formatters!",modelValue);
          return modelValue.join(',');
        });

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
          console.log("Inisde parsers",viewValue);
          return viewValue.split(',');
        });
    
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="SomeApp" ng-controller="SomeAppController" class="container">
  <h4>
    Input a comma separated string
    </h4>
  <input array-model ng-model="inputList">
  <br/> Input List is :{{inputList}}.
  <br/>
  <button type="button" ng-click="removeLastItem()">
    Remove last element from the list
  </button>
</div>
```